# Extension Operator.

Tags: abstract-algebra, category-theory, homological-algebra

I am working on my thesis about completion and extensions from an algebraic point of view. We have the closure operator which takes subsets to subsets with 3 criterias to meet

1. $X\subseteq C(X)$
2. $X\subseteq Y \implies C(X)\subseteq C(Y)$
3. $C(C(X))=C(X)$

Which can be used to describe the completion of a module, which makes sense as it's inspired from the sequences of spaces. This can be used for the completion of modules as well but rather than subsets it would deal with modules. I am curious however if there is an operator for extensions that can be viewed similarly with a list of criterias? With an extension I mean
$$0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$$
Where $A$ is extended by $B$ to give $C$, is there a similar operator that can be thought of to it? I mean as in an operator $E$ such that, in the previous example, we'd have $C=E(A)$ and then $E$ satisfies certain criterias and the criterias are the important one.

Comment: What about injective hulls ? see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Injective_hull

Comment: How could there be such an operator, when there are in general many extensions of $B by $A$?

Comment: Injective hull isn't it and as for how could there be, I am not certain if it can or cannot which is why I ask. There are many ways to complete too, in algebra it depends entirely on the choice of filtration and not all are equivalent.

Comment: What about the following closure operator on the class of (isomorphic types of) your modules? Let a subclass $U$ be **closed** if $A,B\in U$, $0\to A\to C\to B\to 0$ (ex)$\,$ implies $C\in U$.